# How to make QGIS abbreviate labels with a dictionary?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to use qgis "expression dialog" for labeling a layer. What I'm looking for is an expression that permits to apply some abbreviation rules on the layer.
For now i'm using this

```
CASE 
WHEN nome2 is not null THEN  replace("nome1"  || '$' ||  "nome2",  'Wasserfall', 'Wssf.') 
WHEN nome2 is not null THEN  replace("nome1"  || '$' ||  "nome2",  'CascatA', 'Casc.')
WHEN nome2 is not null THEN  replace("nome1"  || '$' ||  "nome2",  'Cascate', 'Casc.e')
WHEN nome2 is null THEN    replace("nome1", 'Wasserfall', 'Wssf.')
WHEN nome2 is null THEN    replace("nome1", 'Cascata', 'Casc.')
WHEN nome2 is null THEN    replace("nome1", 'Cascate', 'Casc.e')
END
```

Obviously it doesn't work because only the first condition (wasserfall) is used for the label.

It happens something like that

Wasserfall$Cascata -> Wssf.$Cascata

instead of

Wasserfall$Cascata -> Wssf.$Casc.

I can solve the problem directly in postgis (with a view or a simple update) but if it is possibile to do it in qgis it would be great.
Most of all it would be great to use an abbreviation dictionary but I'm quite sure that qgis (for now) is not able to doing it.
I'm on W7 qgis 2.4.

Comment: So the rule is 4 letter nome1 and 4 letter nome2?

Comment: Add no I see now, it's more complex then that.

Comment: It's not only a 4 letter, as you see, this is only an example but I have several other words to abbreviate (and abbreviation could have different number of letters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the way I would do this is to create a custom expression function using Python and then we can do exactly what we need.  I wrote about custom expression functions in one of my [blog posts](http://nathanw.net/2012/11/10/user-defined-expression-functions-for-qgis/) but here is how I would do it

```
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

lookups = {'Wasserfall': 'Wssf.',
           'CascatA': 'Casc.' }

@qgsfunction(1, "String")
def abbrev(values, feature, parent):
    # The first value is our string to be changed
    value = values[0]
    # return the short version of the string
    words = value.split()
    newwords = []
    for word in words:
        newword = lookups.get(word, word)
        newwords.append(newword)
    return " ".join(newwords)
```

To use this function you can simply run it in the Python console, or a more permanent way is to add it to your `.qgis2\python\startup.py` file which gets run each time QGIS loads.

You will now find the function in the expression dialog and it can be used like this:

```
abbrev("nome1") || '$' || abbrev("nome2")
```

Comment: Thank you! I've use the function (executed it in Python console) but the problem is that it make a complete substitution not a partial one. If I have "Obere Wasserfall" the label disappear and I obtain the error: File [..]\abbrev.py", line 11, in abbrev return looksups[value] KeyError: u'Obere Wasserfall'

Comment: See the edited function.  It will now split on space, lookup each word, return the shortform, or if not found return the full word, join them back together with spaces and return the result.   This is giving you clues, you will have to tweak depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Complement to answer @Nathan W For french accent and UTF-8 encoding, to [NathanW's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123790/115),
i had to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the head of the code.

**NOW in 2.18:** A new feature 'Substitution list support for labeling'
More informations [here](http://changelog.kartoza.com/en/entry/577).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the substitution list - that is an amazing feature, I used to spend ages messing around with expressions.